# update the selectedindex of many dropdowns

Tags: vb.net

I have a page with 6 category dropdowns, and then a range of questions in 5 sections, each with a dropdown for the answer.

One of the category dropdowns has an answer that renders 2 sections of the questions moot.

To make the page useful I would like to therefore update the answers for the questions in those 2 sections to 'No'. This is already an option within the dropdown, I just need to update all of the relevant lists with that answer.

EDIT: I also need to mention that the questions are created through a repeater and are based on other parameters. As a result I don't necessarily know the names / ids of the dropdowns created.

Comment: How about the `SelectedIndex` attribute?

Comment: @Gordan, I'm not sure what you mean? How would I use it?

Comment: i.e. `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1` or you could do this: `ComboBox1.Text = "No"`

Comment: This is a bad idea from a UX standpoint. If the user accidentally changes the answer in the first section (via keystroke, etc), the answers in the other two sections are lost, requiring the user to go back and reset those answers. It would be better to simply disable or hide those two sections.

Comment: @Cyborgx37, that's a great idea. How do I hide the div? Using an UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a `ComboBox`, you can set it's `SelectedIndex` or it's `Text` attributes.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click()
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 'or you might be able to use 0
    'or
    ComboBox1.Text = "No"
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not using a ComboBox, but rather dropdowns. Also, I need to this display on change of the category dropdown so it would be a 'SelectedIndexChanged' Sub.

Comment: This in part answers my question. I wasn't that clear on what I needed; this gave the correct direction to the solution I eventually implmented - which is a combination of this and @cyborg37's answer.